# how to make asynctask won't update a new data everytime it refresh or changing activity if the json hasn't changed?

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I have this code below that call asynctask and generate notification

```
package apps.skripsi.petvac.navigationmenu;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Days;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

import apps.skripsi.petvac.MainMenu.MainMenuAdapter;
import apps.skripsi.petvac.R;
import apps.skripsi.petvac.Services.RegisterUserClass;
import apps.skripsi.petvac.addpetdata.MainAddPetDataActivity;
import apps.skripsi.petvac.notification.NotificationButtonReceiver;
import apps.skripsi.petvac.parser.JSONParser;
import apps.skripsi.petvac.petinformation.MainPetInformation;
import apps.skripsi.petvac.preference.PreferencesHelper;

/**
 * Created by widi on 9/9/2015.
 */
public class MainMenu extends Fragment {

    FloatingActionButton FAB;
    JSONObject json;
    JSONObject jsonObject;
    PreferencesHelper pref;
    ProgressDialog loading;
    ImageView iv;
    ProgressDialog progress;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout = null;
    ListView list;
    TextView tv;
    int days;
    String result, result2;
    String sisaWaktu, sisa_hari;
    String ID_USER, ID_BINATANG, NAMA_BINATANG, JENIS_BINATANG, FOTO_BINATANG, RAS_BINATANG, TANGGAL_VAKSIN, NAMA_VAKSIN, STATUS_VAKSIN, ID_DATA_WAKTU_VAKSINASI;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listBinatang = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    public static String id_user = "id_user";
    public static String id_binatang = "id_binatang";
    public static String nama_binatang = "nama_binatang";
    public static String jenis_binatang = "jenis_binatang";
    public static String foto_binatang = "foto_binatang";
    public static String ras_binatang = "ras_binatang";
    public static String tanggal_vaksin = "tanggal_vaksin";
    public static String nama_vaksin = "nama_vaksin";
    public static String jumlah_hari;
    public static String status_vaksin = "status_vaksin";
    public static String id_data_waktu_vaksinasi = "id_data_waktu_vaksinasi";

    private Context context;

    private static String url = "http://petvaccination.hol.es/api/data_menu_utama_vaksinasi.php";

    private static String urlgambar = "http://petvaccination.hol.es/imgupload/uploadedimages/";

    private static String delete_url = "http://petvaccination.hol.es/UserRegistration/delete_binatang.php";


    public MainMenu() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_menu_fragment, container, false);

        FAB = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonTambahData);

        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout);


        pref = new PreferencesHelper(getActivity().getBaseContext());

        tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_hewan);

        FAB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent a = new Intent(getActivity(), MainAddPetDataActivity.class);
                startActivity(a);
            }
        });


        try {
            new DataBinatangOperation().execute(url).get(20000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                    new DataBinatangOperation().execute(url);
                    updateList();
            }
        });


        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        context = activity;
    }

    private void updateList() {

        if (mSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }


    private class DataBinatangOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        MainMenuAdapter adapter = new MainMenuAdapter(MainMenu.this,
                listBinatang);

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            JSONArray json;
            try {
                result = JSONParser.getPage(url);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return result;

        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            result2 = pref.getPreferences("json");

            try {
                System.out.print("result = " + result);
                json = new JSONObject(result);
                progress.dismiss();

                JSONArray objek = json.getJSONArray("data_vaksinasi_menu");

                for (int i = 0; i < objek.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jo = objek.getJSONObject(i);

                    ID_USER = jo.getString(id_user);
                    ID_BINATANG = jo.getString(id_binatang);
                    NAMA_BINATANG = jo.getString(nama_binatang);
                    JENIS_BINATANG = jo.getString(jenis_binatang);
                    FOTO_BINATANG = jo.getString(foto_binatang);
                    RAS_BINATANG = jo.getString(ras_binatang);
                    ID_DATA_WAKTU_VAKSINASI = jo.getString(id_data_waktu_vaksinasi);
                    TANGGAL_VAKSIN = jo.getString(tanggal_vaksin);
                    NAMA_VAKSIN = jo.getString(nama_vaksin);
                    STATUS_VAKSIN = jo.getString(status_vaksin);

                    if (pref.getPreferences("ID").equals(ID_USER)) {

                        if (jo.isNull(id_data_waktu_vaksinasi) && jo.isNull(tanggal_vaksin) && jo.isNull(nama_vaksin) && jo.isNull(status_vaksin)) {
                            NAMA_VAKSIN = "belum ada data";
                            sisaWaktu = "";
                        } else {

                            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());

                            Calendar waktuSekarang = Calendar.getInstance();

                            Date date1 = waktuSekarang.getTime();
                            Date date2 = new Date();

                            date2 = formatter.parse(TANGGAL_VAKSIN);

                            if (date2.after(date1)) {
                                days = Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(date1), new DateTime(date2)).getDays();
                                if (days > 7 && days <= 30) {
                                    int weeks = days / 7;
                                    sisa_hari = String.valueOf(days);
                                    sisaWaktu = String.valueOf(weeks) + " minggu";
                                } else if (days > 30 && days <= 365) {
                                    int months = days / 30;
                                    sisa_hari = String.valueOf(days);
                                    sisaWaktu = String.valueOf(months) + " bulan";
                                } else if (days > 365) {
                                    int years = days / 365;
                                    sisa_hari = String.valueOf(days);
                                    sisaWaktu = String.valueOf(years) + " tahun";
                                } else {
                                    sisaWaktu = String.valueOf(days) + " hari";
                                    if (days <= 5) {
                                        sisa_hari = String.valueOf(days);
                                        Log.d("result = ", result);
                                        Log.d("result 2 = ", result2);
                                        createSimpleNotification(context, NAMA_BINATANG, sisa_hari, ID_BINATANG);
                                    }
                                }
                            } else if (date2.before(date1)) {
                                days = Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(date2), new DateTime(date1)).getDays();
                                if (days == 0) {
                                    sisaWaktu = "sekarang";
                                    sisa_hari = String.valueOf(days);
                                    if (STATUS_VAKSIN.equals("belum")) {
                                            createButtonNotification(context, NAMA_BINATANG, sisaWaktu, sisa_hari, ID_BINATANG, ID_DATA_WAKTU_VAKSINASI);
                                    }/*else{
                                        return;
                                    }*/
                                } else {
                                    sisaWaktu = "lewat " + String.valueOf(days) + " hari";
                                    sisa_hari = String.valueOf(days);
                                    if (STATUS_VAKSIN.equals("belum")) {
                                            createButtonNotification(context, NAMA_BINATANG, sisaWaktu, sisa_hari, ID_BINATANG, ID_DATA_WAKTU_VAKSINASI);
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }

                    }

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put(id_binatang, ID_BINATANG);
                    map.put(nama_binatang, NAMA_BINATANG);
                    map.put(jenis_binatang, JENIS_BINATANG);
                    map.put(foto_binatang, urlgambar + FOTO_BINATANG);
                    map.put(ras_binatang, RAS_BINATANG);
                    map.put(tanggal_vaksin, sisaWaktu);
                    map.put(jumlah_hari, sisa_hari);
                    map.put(nama_vaksin, NAMA_VAKSIN);


                    if (pref.getPreferences("ID").equals(ID_USER)) {
                        listBinatang.add(map);

                        System.out.println("hasil list : " + String.valueOf(listBinatang));
                    }


                }

                if (String.valueOf(listBinatang).equals("[]")) {
                    tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }


                System.out.println("adapter : " + String.valueOf(adapter));
                list.setAdapter(adapter);


                list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long idx) {

                        HashMap<String, String> ambilid = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        ambilid = listBinatang.get(position);

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "pindah halaman", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        Intent a = new Intent(getActivity(), MainPetInformation.class);

                        Log.d("sisa ", ambilid.get(MainMenu.jumlah_hari));

                        a.putExtra("IDB", ambilid.get(MainMenu.id_binatang));
                        a.putExtra("IDVAK", ambilid.get(MainMenu.id_data_waktu_vaksinasi));
                        a.putExtra("SW", ambilid.get(MainMenu.jumlah_hari));

                        startActivity(a);
                    }

                });

                list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        HashMap<String, String> ambilid = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        ambilid = listBinatang.get(position);
                        final String idbin = ambilid.get(MainMenu.id_binatang);
                        Log.d("idb ", idbin);

                        AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                        ab.setTitle("Delete Binatang");
                        ab.setMessage("Anda Yakin?");
                        ab.setPositiveButton("Ya", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                delete(idbin);
                                new DataBinatangOperation().execute(url);
                            }
                        });
                        ab.setNegativeButton("Tidak", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            }
                        });
                        ab.show();


                        return true;
                    }
                });

            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            listBinatang.clear();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            pref.savePreferences("json", result);
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Please Wait",
                    "Loading Data", true);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        }
    }

    public void createSimpleNotification(Context context, String nama_binatang, String sisa_hari, String id) {

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainPetInformation.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra("IDB", id);
        resultIntent.putExtra("SW", sisa_hari);
        resultIntent.putExtra("IDVAK", "");

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(getActivity().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        int IntID = Integer.valueOf(id);

        Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        PendingIntent resultPending = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, IntID, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setContentTitle(nama_binatang)
                .setContentText(sisa_hari + " hari lagi")
                .setSound(uri)
                .setContentIntent(resultPending);

        mNotificationManager.notify(IntID, mBuilder.build());
    }

    public void createButtonNotification(Context context, String nama_binatang, String sisa_waktu, String sisa_hari, String idb, String idv) {

        Log.d("idb", idb);

        int IntID = Integer.valueOf(idb);
        int sisaHari = Integer.valueOf(sisa_hari);
        String sisa_hari2;

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainPetInformation.class);

        intent.putExtra("IDB", idb);
        intent.putExtra("IDVAK", idv);
        if (sisaHari > 0) {
            sisa_hari2 = "-" + sisa_hari;
            intent.putExtra("SW", sisa_hari2);
        } else if (sisaHari == 0) {
            intent.putExtra("SW", sisa_hari);
        }

        Intent cancelIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), NotificationButtonReceiver.class);
        cancelIntent.putExtra("notifID", IntID);

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(getActivity().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);


        PendingIntent IntentAccept = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(), IntID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        PendingIntent IntentCancel = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(), IntID, cancelIntent, 0);

        // Building the notifcation
        NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setContentTitle(nama_binatang)
                .setContentText(sisa_waktu)
                .setSound(uri)
                .addAction(R.drawable.accept, "Accept", IntentAccept)
                .addAction(R.drawable.cancel, "Cancel", IntentCancel);

        nBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        mNotificationManager.notify(IntID, nBuilder.build());


    }

    private void delete(String idbinatang) {
        class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            RegisterUserClass ruc = new RegisterUserClass();


            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Please Wait", null, true, true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
                data.put("id_binatang", params[0]);

                String result = ruc.sendPostRequest(delete_url, data);

                Log.d("result ", result);
                return result;
            }
        }

        RegisterUser ru = new RegisterUser();
        ru.execute(idbinatang);

    }

}
```

but everytime I refresh or changing activity, it'll update the new data again and keep generating the notification, even though the json data still hasn't changed yet.

Can somebody give me a solution of how to make it won't update data if the json doesn't change?

Comment: the json data is from api right?

Comment: @GujaratSantana right

Comment: It sounds like you want to cache the results of your AsyncTask.  There are a whole lot of ways you can do this, so maybe you'll want to study up on that, or say very clearly what you would like your caching strategy to be (it can be very complicated).

Answer (score 0):

Here are my tips and hopefully they will be the solution for you:

1. In order to get the data from the server, you need call the api to communicate between your application and the server
2. After getting the data like json from the api, you can manage that data (for example, you can update the ui to reflect the changes).

Your problem: you want the AsyncTask to not call the api because the json or data that comes from server is the same.

My answer: you can't do that, because, basically, AsyncTask is used for the background task, just like you did here, to get data from the server. Hopefully it will help you better understand.